# Error on starting spark with start-all.sh

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I try to start the spark with the script start-all.sh it throws an error as

```
> localhost: failed to launch: nice -n 0 bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081
> spark://dev-pipeline-west-eu.jwn4tgenexauzewylryxtm545b.ax.internal.cloudapp.net:7077
> localhost:       at
> sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(java.base@9-internal/LauncherHelper.java:585)
> localhost:       at
> sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(java.base@9-internal/LauncherHelper.java:497)
> localhost: full log in
> /spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-shankar-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-dev-pipeline-west-eu.out
```

When I looked to the log file available at `/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-shankar-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-dev-pipeline-west-eu.out` has following error log.

```
> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
> try again Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.match(java.base@9-internal/JarFile.java:983)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(java.base@9-internal/JarFile.java:1017)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.isMultiRelease(java.base@9-internal/JarFile.java:399)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(java.base@9-internal/JarFile.java:524)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(java.base@9-internal/JarFile.java:480)
>     at jdk.internal.util.jar.JarIndex.getJarIndex(java.base@9-internal/JarIndex.java:114)
```

What causes the error any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04.
Updating Java fixed the issue:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

java -version

java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: This is an answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**
Use Java version 8 not version 9.

**Option 1**
One option would be to uninstall Java (version 9) and reinstall Java (version 8).  (You can view this posting for installing Java; make sure you make necessary changes so you install version 8.)

**Option 2**
If you have both installed and you are using Ubuntu, you can use this command:

**sudo update-alternatives --config java**

To the prompt you will see, respond with the integer associated with Java 8 and press enter.

Form: 
http://continualintegration.com/miscellaneous-articles/how-do-you-troubleshoot-the-spark-shell-error-a-jni-error-has-occurred